# Is it possible to apply conditional formatting in Google App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table in Google App Maker, I am wondering is it possible to apply conditional formatting to rows of the table.

Example:
If the value of a drop down is "Yes" set that row's background colour to be red.

The documentation regarding this is useless as always and wasn't able to find any questions regarding this.

Image:
[image]

Greyed out Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret is in your bindings. If you wish to retain the regular assigned styles like 'app-ListTableRow' and 'hoverAncestor' then do the following:

Add a class in your Style Editor like this for example:

```
.red {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, darkred, red);
}
```

On your table row 'Display' - styles enter the following binding:

```
@datasource.item.CertificateisRequired === 'Yes' ? ['red','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : ['app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor']
```

That will do it.

If you have a dropdown in each row I would suggest to call it 'CertificateisRequired' instead of leaving a default name like 'DropDown1' or whatever App Maker assigns to it. Then adjust the binding in the row Display - styles to:

```
@widget.descendants.CertificateisRequired.value === 'Yes' ? ['red','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : ['app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor']
```

Comment: Hey Markus, thanks again for the help. If I understand correctly the above will look at the inherited datasource, look at the row(s) and look at the value in CertificateisRequired and if it is yes, apply the styling I set in the Style Editor. (That all makes perfect sense.) Only small problem is CertificateisRequired is not a field in the Certificate's datasource. It's just a plain old drop down widget with a value preset to be "No." Logic is solid though, will try working it out. (Thanks again, awarding as answer.)

Comment: Thanks Markus, tried to add it. The button to "add" style is greyed out though. Will add an image above. What I am trying to add:@widget.descendants.Dropdown_Cert_Required_Value.value === 'Yes' ? ['red','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : ['app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor']

Comment: You have to change the styles setting to binding instead of value. Then paste your binding in. You cannot add a binding as a list item in the styles list. Click on the equal sign in the styles dropdown and it gives you a dropdown of binding or value.